# Fetching the list of filenames in root directory using javascipt

Tags: javascript, string, file

How can I fetch the the filenames on the root directory and store them as strings? Supposedly I have files from server side at *http://192.168.1.10/REPORTS* and can preview them as seen below:

[image]

For example, I declared variables *a, b, c, d, ..*. Then I will store the fetched file names accordingly. a = A_3_3_1.CSV, b = A_3_3_4.CSV, and so on...

This will greatly help me in improving and customizing the UI, unlike what you are seeing. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Fetch the directory using AJAX, store it in the DOM, then use DOM methods to iterate through the elements. Note that there's no standard format for this, HTTP is not a network filesystem protocol.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way you can use ajax to grab the list of files in a directory.

As long as there's no default HTML files in the same directory as the files (e.g. index.html, default.html), the `ajax` will return the page shown in your screenshot. Then it's just a matter of collecting the filenames from the `<a>` tags.

```
const dir = ".";

$.ajax({
    //This will retrieve the contents of the folder if the folder is configured as 'browsable'
    url: dir,
    success: function (data) {         
        $(data).find("a").each(function () {            
            console.log('contents');
            var filename = this.href.split('/').pop();
            $('#FileList').append('<li>'+filename+'</li>');
        });
    }
});
```

If you want to exclude the HTML and JS files you're using to get the list, do that in the `success` callback.

```
if (filename !== 'filelist.html' && filename !== 'filelist.js') {
  $('#FileList').append('<li>'+filename+'</li>');
}
```

If you want to restrict the output to only CSV files, specify that in the `find` function.

```
const fileextension = ".csv";
...

$(data).find("a:contains(" + fileextension + ")").each(function () { 
  ...
}
```